# Does Objectify permit all types of visibility for Entity fields?

Tags: visibility, objectify

The [sample Objectify code](http://code.google.com/p/objectify-appengine/wiki/IntroductionToObjectify#Create_Your_Entity_Classes) shows entity fields declared with default visibility, e.g.,

```
public class Car
{
    @Id Long id;
    String vin;
    int color;
    @Transient String doNotPersist;
}
```

Does it matter if I declare the fields `private`, `protected`, or `public` instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on [this example](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-javadev2-13/?ca=drs-), which I found a few hours after posting my question, persisted fields **can** be private.